# Use for-each in XSLT to iterate a node

Tags: xslt

I have a table and I want to find the maximum entries from tbody and thead. I have mentioned the table code below.

```
<table>
<thead>
<row>
    <entry>
        <p>aaa</p>
        <p>aaa</p>
    </entry>
</row>
<row>
    <entry>
        <p>bbb</p>
        <p>bbb</p>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <p>ccc</p>
        <p>ccc</p>
    </entry>
</row>
</thead>
<tbody>
<row>
    <entry>
        <p>ddd</p>
        <p>ddd</p>
    </entry>
</row>
<row>
    <entry>
        <p>eee</p>
        <p>eee</p>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <p>fff</p>
        <p>fff</p>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <p>ggg</p>
        <p>ggg</p>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <p>hhh</p>
        <p>hhh</p>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <p>iii</p>
        <p>iii</p>
    </entry>
</row>
<row>
    <entry>
        <p>jjj</p>
        <p>jjj</p>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <p>kkk</p>
        <p>kkk</p>
    </entry>
</row>
```

It means here maximum entry count is `5` and it is xpath is `table/tbody/row[2]/entry`. I want to find the maxmium entry value between  `thead` and `tbody`.

Now I want to iterate a node variable value times. I used following code to perform it.

```
 <xsl:when test="$is-notempty-table gt 1">
      <xsl:for-each select="$is-notempty-table">
           <col colname="{position()}"/>
       </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:when>
```

But this not works well. help me to solve this.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The expression I think you want is `<xsl:for-each select="1 to $is-notempty-table">`

Comment: Please (always!) specify what version of XSLT you are using. The solutions will often be different.